# why does c++11 std::array using template to initialize the max_size not constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

c++11 uses template to define the max_size of the array (eg. `std::array<int, 5> a1;`) but not constructor. (eg. `std::array<int>(5) a1;`)

Since template is going to generate code for the class, and if I have a lot of arrays just differs in sizes, there'll be a lot of code to be generated.

(1. It may cause increase in compile time.
 2. It may cause the expension of the code part of the executable file.)

Comment: Because `std::array` wraps an array. It literally contains a `T arr[N];`.

Comment: As template argument, the size is decided in compile time. As constructor argument, the size is decided in construction time (execution time).

Comment: You don't need to worry about generated code size - std::array is designed to be a perfect substitute for "normal" arrays, meaning although the compiler may have to generate some code multiple times, these are mostly optmimizable one-liners that will leave you with the same code as C-Arrays when Optimization is turned on.

Comment: @chris: Well I don't know about the *"literally"* part... :P

Comment: @Mehrdad: Why? It can't be implemented any other way. Or are you being pedantic with the name `arr`?

Comment: @Xeo: lol I'm just pedantic with the word "literally", that's all. The name could've been different, it could've been hiding under a typedef, etc., is all.

Comment: @Xeo, Or the `T`, or the `N`. Such pedantry makes me chuckle because I'm actually that bad most of the time. Consider that rephrased to *For all practical purposes, it contains a `T arr[N];`*.

Comment: @Xeo: Relevant: http://xkcd.com/725/

Comment: @Xeo: Also relevant... http://xkcd.com/1108/

Comment: @Mehrdad: Saw that one coming from a mile. :)

Comment: I don't think there's any better way to prove a point than with xkcd :p

Comment: Interesting. In the german language there is exactly the same misuse of the german word for "literally". Or even literally the same? Never mind...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Aren't you just pedantic? And I literally mean it! http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/literally

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because if it didn't, it wouldn't be able to be what it is.

`std::array` is an *array*. Not a dynamically-sized array. Not a runtime-sized array. It is an *array*, much like `int arr[5]`.

C++ is a statically typed language, which means that C++ types must have a compile-time defined size. `arr` in the above example has a size; if you do `sizeof(arr)`, you will get `sizeof(int) * 5`. `sizeof(std::array<int, 5>)` has a size as well, which is defined by the number of elements in it. Therefore, the size must be a compile-time defined quantity, since it factors into the compile-time defined size.

The differences between `std::array` and regular arrays are:

- Arrays will decay into pointers implicitly. `std::array` does not; you need to explicitly call a function to do that.
- Arrays are language arrays; `std::array`, to the language, is a struct which contains an array.

> if I have a lot of arrays just differs in sizes, there'll be a lot of code to be generated.

Yes, you might. Then again... is this a serious concern? Have you really *looked* at a `std::array` implementation?

There's not much there. `T operator[](int index) { return elems[index]; }` I don't think getting a couple hundred instantiations of *that* function is going to be a problem. Same goes for `begin`, `size`, `empty`, etc. You're talking about code that will almost certainly be inlined.

Comment: "If you do `sizeof(std::array<int, 5>)`, you'll get the same thing." -- Does the standard really guarantee that? Why can't `std::array` have trailing padding like any other class type?

Comment: @hvd Who said `std::array` can not have padding? `std::array<char,3>` will have (at least on most platforms)

Comment: @BЈовић Nicol did in this answer. "The same thing" refers to `sizeof(int) * 5`, does it not?

Comment: Thanks for editing, but it still doesn't look right: `arr` *cannot* have padding in `int arr[5];`. `sizeof(int[5])` must be exactly `sizeof(int) * 5`. `sizeof(std::array<int, 5>)` can be larger.

Comment: I've read the assembly code generated and I know that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`std::array` is meant as a thin wrapper over a fixed-sized array. For a dynamically-sized array, there is `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of `std::array` is that it allocates memory on the *stack* (unless you declare a  global object) with minimal overhead.

If the array size was determined by a constructor parameter, allocation would have to be on the *heap* and in general the resulting object would be less efficient in terms of memory usage and performance.